# How can I import ADDED BY field of Activities?

Tags: import, activities

I have data in spreadsheet. How can I import Activities with respective **Added by** values (specified in spreadsheet)?

Can't find this field in CiviCRM Activities import tool.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Selecting the Source Contact should do the trick.